# Exclude cache if specific URL parameter exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use cache in .aspx page (**ASP.NET 4**) like this:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="100000" VaryByParam="CategoryID" %>
```

Every thing is fine, until when the page url have `traceid` I need don't use any cache.

So is there any way to exclude cache when 'traceid' exist in the URL parameters?
any suggestion?

Comment: You can't do this via the OutputCache directive. You would have to implement this entirely on code.

Comment: @Icarus OK, How could I do this? any suggestion?

Comment: By setting the appropriate response headers, which is exactly the same thing the OutputCache directive does. I am writing from a cell phone so it's difficult for me to write a full working example but I will provide pseudo code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also found something that's worked for me:

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("traceid"))
            HttpContext.Current.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        base.OnPreInit(e);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(Requesq.QueryString["trace_id"]== null)
 {
    Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=86400");
    //and any other header that may be needed to instruct a browser that it should cache the response
    Response.AddHeader("Vary",...
 }
```

I would fire up the Developer tools in Chrome (Hit F12) and analyze all the response headers sent on your current page and use those as an example of the headers you need to set on each Response. That way you don't add those headers when the query string has the trace_id in it.